# How to get controller and action name in zf2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

in zf1, we can get controller and action name using

```
$controller = $this->getRequest()->getControllerName();
$action = $this->getRequest()->getActionName();
```

How we can achieve this in zf2?

UPDATE:
I tried to get them using

```
echo $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('action', 'NA');
echo $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('controller', 'NA');
```

But I am getting error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getParam() on a non-object
```

I like to get them in __construct() method;

Ideally I would like to check if there is no Action is defined it will execute noaction() method. I would check using php method method_exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can't access these variables in controller `__construct()` method, but you can access them in `dispatch` method and `onDispatch` method.

but if you would like to check whether action exist or not, in zf2 there is already a built in function for that notFoundAction as below

```
 public function notFoundAction()
{
    parent::notFoundAction();
    $response = $this->getResponse();
    $response->setStatusCode(200);
    $response->setContent("Action not found");
    return $response;   
}
```

but if you still like to do it manually you can do this using dispatch methods as follow

```
namespace Mynamespace\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

use Zend\Stdlib\RequestInterface as Request;
use Zend\Stdlib\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController 
{

    public function __construct()
    {


    }        

      public function notFoundAction()
    {
        parent::notFoundAction();
        $response = $this->getResponse();
        $response->setStatusCode(200);
        $response->setContent("Action not found");
        return $response;   
    }

    public function dispatch(Request $request, Response $response = null)
    {
        /*
         * any customize code here
         */

        return parent::dispatch($request, $response);
    }
    public function onDispatch(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $action = $this->params('action');
        //alertnatively 
        //$routeMatch = $e->getRouteMatch();
        //$action = $routeMatch->getParam('action', 'not-found');

        if(!method_exists(__Class__, $action."Action")){
           $this->noaction();
        }

        return parent::onDispatch($e);
    }
    public function noaction()
    {        
        echo 'action does not exits';   
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, when I insert your code to my controller, the browser show nothing (as server send no data). Could you tell me what happen? Thank you

Answer (score 13):

Even simpler:

```
$controllerName =$this->params('controller');
$actionName = $this->params('action');
```

Comment: it is not working. same error Fatal error: Call to a member function getParam() on a non-object. Am I doing something wrong?? Do I need to use any name space or extend any class? I am calling this in __contruct() method.

Comment: Are you doing this call from a Controller? What ZF2 version are you using?

Comment: beta5, actually i think these variables are not accessiable in __construct method of controller. but can be acccessiable in dispatch and onDispatch methods.

Comment: I missed that __constructor part! You will not be able to call them there unless you do some special operations. See this post for some more information:http://mwop.net/blog/2012-07-30-the-new-init.html

Answer (score 0):

You will get module , controller and action name like this in Zf2 inside your controller...

```
$controllerClass = get_class($this);
$moduleNamespace = substr($controllerClass, 0, strpos($controllerClass, '\\'));
$tmp = substr($controllerClass, strrpos($controllerClass, '\\')+1 );
$controllerName = str_replace('Controller', "", $tmp);

//set 'variable' into layout...
$this->layout()->currentModuleName      = strtolower($moduleNamespace);
$this->layout()->currentControllerName  = strtolower($controllerName);
$this->layout()->currentActionName      = $this->params('action');
```

Answer (score -6):

```
$controllerName = strtolower(Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getControllerName());
```

Comment: The author of the question asked for zf2 implementation, not zf1