# How to get action name in Laminas framework constructor

Tags: laminas

Getting the action name within an action is simple - I can use the "actionName" parameter.
But is there a way to get the action name in the constructor of the Controller?

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $action = $this->params('actionName');
    }
```

Comment: Not sure I understand exactly, can you paste a full code with your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor in the Controller-Class does not know yet which action is called. However, You could extend the `onDispatch`-method in the [AbstractActionController.php](https://github.com/laminas/laminas-mvc/blob/4.0.x/src/Controller/AbstractActionController.php#L59-L82) which is called **before** any action is called but **after** the `__construct()`-method is called. Something like this:

```php
<?php
...
use Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent; # <-- add this

class YourController extends AbstractActionController
{
    
    public function onDispatch(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $this->action = $this->params()->fromRoute('action');

        // Or somethink like e.g.:
        if ($this->params()->fromRoute('action') == 'foo') {
          // do something
        }

        return parent::onDispatch($e);
        
    }
}
```